# Unable to copy files in a set working folder by using "get" command line (visual sourcesafe)

Tags: recursion, directory, command-prompt, visual-sourcesafe

I'm trying to "extract" the labelled folders of a project (Versioned by VSS) in a working folder, previously set. The commands which I am using in the command line are: 
ss Workfol "$/Project" "C:\Path of the working folder"
n.b. after this command, a line on the screen informs me that the working folder has been set as requested

and

ss Get $/Project -R

After this command the program asks if I want to set the VSS folder as a default working folder (I press N for Not), and all the file names appear on the screen. The problem is that, when I check in the working folder which i set with the first command, it is still empty.
Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Maybe I found a solution in this old post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638540/sourcesafe-command-line-options

Comment: I have a problem with the "get" command....if I have some branched folders inside my project...this folders don't appear in the workinf folder where I copy all the files obtained through get. And it has sense, since get works only by copying files and not even the folders but....what command should I use to have even the folders?